# Simple HTML formatting for Outlook Email Signature

Tags: html, css, ios, outlook

I am running into a problem creating an HTML signature for Outlook mobile. I want it to exactly match the signature (used firmwide) I have for my desktop outlook. See below for a picture.

[image: Signature I want]

Currently, I am using this code and while the layout is correct, I cannot get the font to change colors. When I draft an email the font is the correct color but once sent, it changes to black. Any ideas?

```html
<table style="
            border-collapse:collapse;
            border:none;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="
                    width: 467.5pt;
                    border-top: none;
                    border-right: none;
                    border-bottom: none;
                    border-image: initial;
                    border-left: 1.5pt solid rgb(0, 168, 126);
                    padding: 0 0.15in;
                    height: 0.25in;
                    vertical-align: top;">
            <p style="
                    margin: 0 0 .0001pt;
                    font-size:15px;
                    font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;">
                <strong>
                    <span style="
                            font-size:16px;
                            font-family:Garamond,serif;
                            color:#003B4C;">
                        FirstName LastName
                    </span>
                </strong>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="
                width: 467.5pt;
                border-top: none;
                border-right: none;
                border-bottom: none;
                border-image: initial;
                border-left: 1.5pt solid rgb(0, 168, 126);
                padding: 0 0.15in;
                height: 9.9pt;
                vertical-align: top;">
            <p style="
                    margin: 0 0 .0001pt;
                    font-size: 15px;
                    font-family: Calibri,sans-serif;">
                <span style="
                        font-size: 12px;
                        font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
                        color:#003B4C;">
                    t.&nbsp;
                </span>
                <span style="
                        font-size: 12px;
                        font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
                        color: #003B4C;
                        text-decoration: none;">
                    +1 (123) 456-7891
                </span>
                <span style="
                        font-size: 12px;
                        font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
                        color: #003B4C;">
                    &nbsp;| m.&nbsp;
                </span>
                <span style="
                        font-size: 12px;
                        font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
                        color: #003B4C;
                        text-decoration: none;">
                    +1 (123) 456-7891
                </span>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with _I cannot get the font to change colors_? If I replace the color in your code to say `#FF0000` I get red text so it seems to change colors (for me at least)

Comment: Once I save the above code in my signature block in Outlook Mobile (iphone), I click "New Message" to draft an email. The signature populates in the draft and the font is the correct color per the html #003B4C.

However, when I send the email, the recipient sees the font in black. Everything else works fine except the font color.

Comment: Solved  - may have been a server issue because I sent test emails this morning and the font color is now correctly changing.